# Unbox Parsing Generic Type

Tags: swift, unbox

I tried to find out but couldn't fine any solution. So, asking you guys.

Is there any chance to write a func which is return as generic type?

I have a structure as below

```
struct WWSInterest: Unboxable {
    var confirmation: Bool
    var data: [WWSKeyValue]?
    var message: String?

    init(unboxer: Unboxer) throws {
        self.confirmation = try! unboxer.unbox(key: "confirmation")
        self.data = try? unboxer.unbox(key: "data")
        self.message = try? unboxer.unbox(key: "message")
    }

//    static func createFrom(data: Data) -> WWSInterest? {
//        do {
//            let r: WWSInterest = try unbox(data: data)
//            return r
//        } catch {
//            return nil
//        }
//    }
}
```

and i want to helper func like below

```
func create<T>(from data: Data) -> T? {
    do {
        let r: T = try unbox(data: data)
        return r
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Is that possible?

BTW: Sorry my bad English

> // Edit

WWSKeyValue is struct as below,

```
struct WWSKeyValue: Unboxable {
    var key: String
    var value: String

    init(unboxer: Unboxer) throws {
        self.key = try! unboxer.unbox(key: "key")
        self.value = try! unboxer.unbox(key: "value")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it yourself? If it didn't work, what's the error message? And what is the `unbox` method doing?

Comment: What's `Unboxable`? What's `WWSKeyValue`? Can you add the declarations of those two to the question, to better understand your problem domain?

Comment: Hi, `unbox` and `Unboxable comes from [this pod](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox).

When i uncomment commented createFrom func, xcode says "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".

Comment: Since Swift 4 all third-party JSON parser have become obsolete in favor of the built-in `Codable` protocol.